# Spring-Security 5 OAuth2 authentication against ADFS 2016

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, adfs

I'm trying to setup my spring-boot 2.2.0 application to authenticate users on my ADFS 2016 using OAuth2.

Unfortunately it doesn't work as at every requests the AFS give me this error:

> MSIS9604: An error occurred. The authorization server was not able to fulfill the request.

And in the ADFS event log, I've this :

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Parameter name: issuer

   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.JSON.JsonWebSecurityToken.Initialize(String issuer, String audience, DateTime validFrom, DateTime validTo, IEnumerable`1 claims)    
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.JSON.JsonWebSecurityToken..ctor(String issuer, String audience, DateTime validFrom, DateTime validTo, SigningCredentials signingCredentials, IEnumerable`1 claims)    
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthProtocolHandler.CreateIdToken(String clientId, String nonce, SessionSecurityToken ssoToken, JsonWebSecurityToken accessToken, List`1 userInfoClaims)    
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthProtocolHandler.BuildTokenResponseWithSerializedToken(OAuthProtocolContext context, WrappedHttpListenerContext httpContext, Uri originalRequestBaseUri, SecurityTokenElement signOnTokenElement, ArtifactSecurityTokenType originalTokenType, String clientId, String clientRedirectUri, String resource, Boolean isKmsiRequested, String authMethod)    
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.OAuth.OAuthAuthorization.OAuthAuthorizationProtocolHandler.CreateAuthorizationResponseMessage(OAuthAuthorizationRequestContext authorizationContext, SecurityToken ssoSecurityToken, Boolean ssoSignInAttempted)
```

What is this issuer param ? Is there a code sample available somewhere to connect spring-security 5 Oauth2 to ADFS 2016 ?

Comment: Hitting this same issue, did you end up finding a solution to this?

Comment: I don't know if you got a solution for your query or not.If not,you can have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55474990/6039674 .It was helpful for me.